# Как работают символы перенаправления

Tags: shell

У меня в конце выполнения программы выполняется такая команда:

```
tar -x <&3
```

Подскажите что обозначают последние 3 символа.

Comment: Перенаправление данных из файлового дескриптора 3 в стандартный ввод tar